# HttpUrlConnection throws IOException in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make my application communicate with my php server, but am confuse here this app works fine in my android phone, but when i send this same app to my friends for review they coundn't signup because it throws IOException.

I know there are many related questions, but none of them solve my own problem.

```
     @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        con.setReadTimeout(15000);
                        con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    
                        try {
                            if(con.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                                String json;
                                //con.getInputStream().
    
                                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    sb.append(json + "\n");
                                }
    
                                return sb.toString().trim();
                            }
    
                            return "400";
    
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                           //401 is returned once they hit the signup button
  e.printStackTrace();
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return "401";
                        }
    
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return "402";
                    }
                }
```

when my friends try to signup they get "401" as error code set by me

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {
                       //401 is returned once they hit the signup button
                        return "401";
                    }` You should add e.prSTackTrace() there and return e.getMessage(). The same with that other catch block. You do not know if it is 401 0r 402.

Comment: Sorry what i want t know exactly is what will make it work fine with my own android and throw IOException in some android device

Comment: @blackapps even if i have to print the e.prStackTrace this error may not be discover from my device since it works fine, it will be a lot stress to build it, send to friends and ask them to send the error back to me

Comment: Only e.getMessage() will tell you and your friends what is going on. You think they only can report three digits? I think you underestimate them ;-).

Comment: @blackapps i have done that, now the app still works fine with my phone but crash once the button is hit with  my friends. I just try to show e.getMessage() from Toast and it crashing the app

Comment: Aha... But you cannot display a Toast()_ in doInBackground. It will let your app crash ;-). You should return e.getMessage() there and display the Toast in onPostExecute(). ALSO IN THAT OTHER CATCH BLOCK!

Answer (score 0):

I already resolve the issue. I found out that my friends phone are running more higher version of android os from 9 while it work well on my 8.1.0.
Since am making server request through http and not https, android 9 pie will not allow this for security reason. So i simply make my request through https instead if http.